# After applying imputation np.nan values is still present

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have used SimpleImputer to change df but empty rows is still present. What did I do wrong?

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 


imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='most_frequent')
imp.fit_transform(df)
msno.matrix(df)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WldQM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit_transform` is not **in place** transformation, it returns transformed object

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 


imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='most_frequent')
data_without_nans = imp.fit_transform(df)
```

Comment: but using that way df becomes np array and missing will not draw matrix and result in error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'notnull'

Comment: correct, scikit learn is not designed for dataframes, it operates over arrays, you can reassign it to your dataframe in a way you find fit.